# How can you determine whether a solution is dilute or concentrated given its concentration?

Tags: concentration

How can you determine whether a solution is dilute or concentrated given its concentration? I don't whether this is a stupid question or not but I couldn't find any answer.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's stupid. But stop and consider if I point to a random object of known dimensions and ask if it is big or small.

Comment: Unfortunately it is near impossible in chemistry to give absolute *rules of thumb.* Rather a *rules of thumb* is just a "rule" that typically works, but for which there are always exceptions. So for aqueous solutions I'd say that anything less than 0.1 molar would be "dilute." The key notion here being that the various equilibria are dependent on activities not concentrations. But for 0.1 molar solutions or less, the activity should be well approximated by the molar concentration.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/54049/under-which-criteria-hno3-is-a-concentrated-or-a-diluted-acid

Comment: There are definite answers for *saturated* or not (or even *supersaturated*), which have definite limits, but *concentrated* is a matter of opinion, except at the *extrema*.

Answer (score 3):

There is no hard and fast definition of "concentrated" or dilute.  For example, concentrated HCl generally refers to a 12 mol/L solution of HCl.  Concentrated sulfuric acid is 18 mol/L.  When we refer to a "concentrated" solution, we are generally referring to the most concentrated solution that you can prepare, or that you can buy from a supplied.
https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/chemistry/stockroom-reagents/learning-center/technical-library/reagent-concentrations.html